# Wordpress: Load iframe only onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe

I have some external content which I am displaying via iframes on my Wordpress site. The content is very heavy(5mb+) and my site is taking too much time to load. Can I keep a placeholder image and when user clicks on the placeholder then only the iframe loads up?

I tried BJ Lazy Load plugin but that fires the iframe upon user scroll, i want user onclick.

Comment: Even if youll add a trigger that will display the iframe. The load time will be the same. Why? Because the site resources that's inside your iframe is so heavy that the browser needs to download them all before rendering them on the frame.

I can name 2 factors which affects the loading speed of your iframe.
1. Your internet speed - download rate affects it.
2. PC Specs/Browser and its version

Comment: Hi Tibs, thanks for your revert. How can I stop the browser to render content by default & only render when a user clicks on the element?

Comment: You can use bootstrap's modal. Though it will just hide the iframe and loads it 'secretly'.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of quick and dirty. I'm assuming you're using float-based layout, as opposed to Flexbox.

```
<styles>
    #your-iframe {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
    }

    #iframe-wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }

    #iframe-placeholder {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #iframe-placeholder img {
        width: 100%;
    }
</styles>

<div id="iframe-wrapper">
  <div id="iframe-placeholder">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/10/15/13/water-3214232_640.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <iframe id="your-iframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    var yourIframe = document.getElementById('your-iframe');
    var iframeLoader = document.getElementById('iframe-placeholder');
    var iframeSrc = 'https://autotrader.com'

    iframeLoader.addEventListener('click', function() {
        yourIframe.src = iframeSrc;
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }, false);
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45p2zewo/23/)

Comment: getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

and can I remove the button and have the listener on image click?

Comment: Is your script under the iframe and button elements? Also, is your content external to your site? If not, does it have to be in an iframe? If the content isn't a webpage, I would recommend a div with a CSS overflow-y:scroll property. That way you can make the div clickable, while still scrollable like an iframe.

Comment: Yes, its working now. How can i remove the button and make it work when user clicks on my placeholder image?

Comment: Could you answer, is your content external to your site? If not, does it have to be in an iframe?

Comment: Yes its external html page

Comment: See my updated answer with working JSFiddle. For the record, this feels hacky to me.